# Validating nested json properties in loopback

Tags: node.js, validation, loopbackjs

One of my loopback models have structure like:

```
{
    "name":{
        "first":"sam",
        "last":"billings"
     }
}
```

Is it possible to "require" validate "first" and "last" properties? I know that first level properties can be validated by giving "required":true, but how can I validate the nested properties? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can your custom validation like :

```
Model.validateAsync('name', customValidator, {message: 'Name is not correct'});

function customValidator(err, done){
  process.nextTick(() => {
    if (!this.name || !this.name.first || !this.name.last) err();
    done();
  });
}
};
```

Comment: It shows : TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: @DevStar I updated my answer. I don't know why sync validation doesn't work